# Using REST API to verify email and sign up user (Dart and Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to sign up user using REST API. I am so far able to signup user without verification. However, I need to verify the user's email by sending a confirmation email and then sign up the user after confirmation. How can I accomplish that?

Here's my current code:

```
class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  String _token;
  DateTime _expiryDate;
  String _userId;
   Timer _authTimer;

  String get token {
    if (_expiryDate != null &&
        _expiryDate.isAfter(DateTime.now()) &&
        _token != null) {
      return _token;
    }
  }

  bool get isAuth {
    return token != null;
  }

  String get userId{ 
    return _userId; 
  }

  Future<void> _authenticate(
      String email, String password, String urlSegment) async {
    final url =
        '`https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty`/$urlSegment?key={MyAPIKEY}';

    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode(
          {
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
            'returnSecureToken': true,
          },
        ),
      );
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      if (responseData['error'] != null) {
        throw HttpException(responseData['error']['message']);
      }

      _token = responseData['idToken'];
      _userId = responseData['localId'];
      _expiryDate = DateTime.now()
          .add(Duration(seconds: int.parse(responseData['expiresIn'])));
    
     notifyListeners(); 
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  Future<void> signup(String email, String password) async {
    return _authenticate(email, password, 'signupNewUser');
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about the general process or technical details like sending an email?

Comment: I am asking about how to go about implementing the verification/confirmation process in detail.

Comment: @derpirscher, any ideas ?

Comment: Still not sure, what you are asking. Generally a process works as follows: 1. The user sends registration details to the API, which are stored together with some random token generated  on the server. 2. Send an email with that token to the user 3. Ask user to enter token. 4. If the token matches, create the account with the previously entered details. But as I never worked with flutter, I cannot provide any technical details ...